# How to draw the same shape efficiently at different positions and label efficiently?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Here is the code, which is working fine:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
    \draw (1,2)-- (1,4) -- (8,4) -- (8,2) -- cycle;
    \draw (6,4) -- (8,4) -- (8,11) -- (6,11) -- cycle;
    \draw (6,11) -- (6,13) -- (13,13) -- (13,11) -- cycle;
    \node at (1,2) {\textbullet};
    \node at (13,13) {\textbullet};
    \node[below] at (1,2) {$(1,2)$};
    \node[above] at (13,13) {$(13,13)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am sure there must be a way to draw up the three rectangles in an effective way.

Also, how could I label the points (\textbullet) as well as the coordinates in a more compact way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, you want to optimize the code of the question. All these operations can be put in *one* `\draw` command. Then the command form `\tikz` instead of the environment can be used. The path construction can be simplified via `rectangle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[scale=.3]\draw
    (1, 2)
    node {\textbullet}
    node[below] {$(1, 2)$}
    rectangle (8, 4)
    rectangle (6, 11)
    rectangle (13, 13)
    node {\textbullet}
    node[above] {$(13, 13)$}
  ;
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice! Another option not shorter but more compact: `... node [label=below:{$(1,2)$}] {\textbullet} ...`

Comment: @Ignasi I have tried, but the distance is much larger.

Comment: Ups. You're right, with `label`, textbullet node size places label far away, while with a second node the reference is a coordinate a not a node.

Answer (score 4):

Just a possible solution. Instead of lines, use a rectangular node which fits desired coordinates. After that, place label and points using anchors.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, box/.style={draw, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
    \node[fit={(1,2) (8,4)}, box] (a){};
    \node[fit={(6,4) (8,11)}, box] (b){};
    \node[fit={(6,11) (13,13)}, box] (c){};
    \draw[fill] (a.south west) circle (5pt) node[below] {$(1,2)$};
    \draw[fill] (c.north east) circle (5pt) node[above] {$(13,13)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]